# Authorization:REDACTED when executing an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, pulumi-azure

I am observing `Authorization:REDACTED` in the log stream attached to my Azure Function.

**Context:**

Note, that I can execute the same function successfully when I run the Function App in the debugger within my Visual Studio session, using local host.

**Details:**

```
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
User-Agent:azsdk-net-Storage.Blobs/12.13.0,(.NET 6.0.11; Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393)
x-ms-date:Wed, 01 Feb 2023 19:42:49 GMT
Authorization:REDACTED
client assembly: Azure.Storage.Blobs
```

The Azure Function was deployed using Pulumi.

FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION : ~4

**Verifications:**

- I verified that the Azure Function's URL referenced in my client app is valid and matches the URL in the Azure portal for the Azure Function I want to invoke
- I executed the Azure Function from local host without issue.

Comment: Have you tried (first) manually deploying the Azure Function from Visual Studio / Functions runtime / Azure CLI? Are you able to remote debug? Does the Function use external libraries that might be causing issues? Do other Functions in the same Function App work? Based on the current information it's almost impossible to determine the issue.

Comment: I deleted my Pulumi stack and am now running into a different issue: Authorization:REDACTED.

 I'll edit this post to reflect the new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below findings if that helps to fix your issue:

When I run the Pulumi Serverless Function (CSharp) in Visual Studio locally, I got the below output:

[image]

Not Sure the cause of the issue because I tried Pulumi Stack for the 1st time.

And I have identified the similar issue registered in MS Q&A Forum #[1163056](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1163056/getting-authorization-redacted-error-when-running?orderby=helpful) and the user @*MayankBargali-MSFT* given the accepted solution to check the local storage emulator is running on the specified ports each with each Storage object such as Blob, Queue, Table.